# Where else, if possible, can I find the code for functions inside Function App?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

My original method of being able to see code was going to the Azure Portal > Function App > Function > clicking Code + test. Although for this Function App, the only file I can see for the functions inside of it, is the function.json file. I also tried going to advanced tools heading to kudu > debug, still only seeing the function.json in there as well.

I'm not the original author of this Function App, so I was just wondering if there was still a possible method to be able see the code online?

Comment: I wouldn't expect the original source code to be available in the compiled/deployed application.  Source code would be kept in a source control repository somewhere.

Comment: @David Ah, okay interesting. In the code I'd written for my Function App, that I deployed using Visual Studio Code, I can see all my code under "Code + test". However, for this Function App's code I'm trying to access, I'm pretty sure they're using DevOps..

Answer (score 0):

DevOps is being used and I found the repo under the "Deployment Center" option found inside of the Function App in the portal. After some searching in the repo, I've seemed to have found what I was looking for.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).